# How to apply a where condition on average function results without second select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel 6 application. I want to use eloquent to collect only those employees that have an engaged score equal to true.

The question is how can I apply a `where` clause on the `avg` function results without a second select in Eloqunt? For example something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    `employees`.*,
    AVG(responses.text_answer) > 4.6 AS engaged
FROM
    `employees`
INNER JOIN `responses` AS `responses`
ON
    `responses`.`employee_id` = `employees`.`id`
INNER JOIN `survey_questions` AS `surveyQuestions`
ON
    `surveyQuestions`.`id` = `responses`.`survey_question_id`
INNER JOIN `questions` AS `questions`
ON
    `questions`.`id` = `surveyQuestions`.`question_id`
WHERE
    engaged = 1 AND `questions`.`question_type_id` = '6S'
GROUP BY
    `employees`.`id`
```

But the problem is `engaged` in the WHERE condition here is not recognized and MySQL shows:

> Unknown column 'engaged' in 'where clause'

A part of my eloquent statement is like this:

```php
public function engaged()
    {
        return $this->relatedToMany(QuestionType::class, function(Builder $query){
            if(!$this->joined($query, 'responses')){
                $query->join(
                    'responses AS responses',
                    'responses.employee_id',
                    '=',
                    'employees.id',
                    'inner'
                );
            }
            if(!$this->joined($query, 'survey_questions')){
                $query->join(
                    'survey_questions AS surveyQuestions',
                    'surveyQuestions.id',
                    '=',
                    'responses.survey_question_id',
                    'inner'
                );
            }
            if(!$this->joined($query, 'questions')){
                $query->join(
                    'questions AS questions',
                    'questions.id',
                    '=',
                    'surveyQuestions.question_id',
                    'inner'
                );
            }
            $query->where('questions.question_type_id', '6S');
            $query->select('employees.*', \DB::raw('AVG(`responses`.`text_answer`) >= 4.6 AS `engaged`'));
            $query->groupBy('employees.id');
        });
    }
```

And the where clause applied like this:

```php
public function filterEngaged(EloquentBuilder $query, $method, $clauseOperator, $value, $column, $table)
{
    call_user_func([$query, $method], $column, $value);
    // $method = 'where', $column = 'engaged' , $value = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply a `WHERE` condition to an aggregate function. Databases evaluate the `WHERE` clause first, and then aggregate later.

Instead, you can use a `HAVING` clause for this (it is evaluated *after* the `GROUP BY` clause).

So you would need to change this:

```
WHERE 
    engaged = 1 AND `questions`.`question_type_id` = '6S'
GROUP BY
    `employees`.`id`
```

To:

```
WHERE 
    `questions`.`question_type_id` = '6S'
GROUP BY
    `employees`.`id`
HAVING
    engaged = 1
```

In Lavarel, this should look like:

```
$query->where('questions.question_type_id', '6S');
$query->select('employees.*', \DB::raw('AVG(`responses`.`text_answer`) >= 4.6 AS `engaged`'));
$query->groupBy('employees.id');
$query->havingRaw('engaged = 1');
```

Comment: I have tested the havingRaw function also before posting. But now that you said I did a deeper investigation and I saw as I applied the having raw before the groupBy it will be gone by Eloquent.  I have to move my filter function to after of groupBy somehow. Anyway thanks.