# How to pass a function to Having in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can pass a function to `where` function in Laravel to generating conditions in the run time. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548073/laravel-advanced-wheres-how-to-pass-variable-into-function) it showed how can we use function as a parameter in where clause in Eloquent.

```php
DB::table('users')->where(function ($query) use ($activated) {
    $query->where('activated', '=', $activated);
})->get();
```

But when I use the same logic for `havingRaw` function then it makes the following error:

> "message": "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string",
>       "exception": "ErrorException",
>       "file": "C:\xampp7\htdocs\sample_proj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php",
>       "line": 653,

Is there any possibility to apply the `having` conditions like what is possible for `where`?

Comment: This should work fine, what is the type of your `$activated` variable?

Comment: using `having` with `groupBy()` ??

Comment: please send your format of  `$activated` variablre

Comment: $activated is boolean (1)

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari, could you please share `var_dump($activated)` output anyway?

Comment: I tested with `having` and it shows another error: >"message": "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given",

Comment: the `var_dump` is `string(1) "1"`

Comment: If you want more details that what I want to do look here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031020/how-to-apply-a-where-condition-on-average-function-results-without-second-select/60031040#60031040
I use https://github.com/esbenp/bruno for filtering and its custom filter only accept `where` I want to extend it for `having` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

havingRaw expects just a string parameter and won't work with a closure.  You can use the whereHas method like the where method - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: No, I tested and it was not also compile the closuer that `where` can compile it,